# flask receiving url changes from pushstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I'm trying to get the changes made from window.history.pushState onto my flask server. For example, if I do this:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "?firstchange=done");
```

How do I get the "done" String in flask? I have a template under the client route, and I want a function that gets the firstchange query string when it is available.

```
@app.route("/client")
def initial_template():
    return render_template('client.html')

@app.route("/client")
def get_change():
    print request.args.get('firstchange')
```

The return when I call this in other functions after the url changes to http://127.0.0.1:5000/client?firstchange=done is "None" instead of "done".

Edit:

How do you do this using

```
window.location.href('127.0.0.1:5000/client?firstchange=done')
```

With the same flask methods I am still getting returns of "None". Can I not use the get_change method in other methods to determine the query string value?

Comment: Push state happens on the client side, Flask is only server side. You'd have to do `window.location.href('/client?firstchange=done')` or use AJAX.

Comment: See edit for new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how can you register two methods under the same routes, but I don't think it's a good idea and how your flask server will behave.
So, please, change one of your routes.
Here're two ways for doing so:

1)

```
@app.route("/client")
def initial_template():
    return render_template('client.html')

@app.route("/client_state")
def get_change():
    print request.args.get('firstchange')
```

In this case your javascript redirect code will look like this:
window.location.href('127.0.0.1:5000/client_state?firstchange=done')

2)

```
@app.route("/client")
def initial_template():
    return render_template('client.html')

@app.route("/client/<state>")
def get_change(state):
    print state
```

And in this case your javascript redirect code will look like this:
window.location.href('127.0.0.1:5000/client/done')

Take a look at [this documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing) for further questions.